# Nginx Reverse Proxy to ASP.net Core Kestrel 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: nginx, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel, bad-gateway

We have Nginx reverse proxy in the front of Azure Website App Service, built by ASP.net Core program with Kestrel on IIS.

However, only a few people got 502 Bad Gateway error.

Is there anyone engaged similar problem or has solution for this?

Comment: What does your nginx error log say?

Comment: 03:42:59 [error] 116818#116818: *1452587 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 70.95.92.201, server: xxx, request: "GET /xxxxxxx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "

Comment: Seems the Nginx has still enabled response buffering even we disabled proxy_buffering, so we turned the buffering on again and increased the buffer size. It looks good so far...